# Edit /srv folder

Tags: root

How can I get access to edit the /srv folder and all of its contents on ubuntu 12?
I need to edit some files for a server called airtime. I need read and write privileges in it.

Cameron

Answer (score 1):

`/srv` is owned by `root` by default, therefore you need to acquire root privileges to edit it or to add files to it.

You can execute a command with root privileges by [prepending `sudo`](http://www.wikihow.com/Become-Root-in-Ubuntu) to it:

```
[timwolla@/srv]ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 17  2012 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 Mar 18 16:20 ..
[timwolla@/srv]mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Permission denied
[timwolla@/srv]sudo mkdir test
[sudo] password for timwolla: 
[timwolla@/srv]ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mar 26 20:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 Mar 18 16:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Mar 26 20:20 test
```

Comment: is this command line only? Any way i can use the GUI for root/sudo privleges?

Comment: @CameronTarbell You can use `gksudo` to start a graphical program with root privileges. The file manager is called `nautilus`.